# github actions not discovering artifacts uploaded between runs

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a set of static binaries that I am currently re-downloading every CI run. I need these binaries to test against. I would like to cache these OS specific binaries on github actions so i don't need to re-download them everytime.

**A key consideration here is the binaries do not change between jobs, they are 3rd party binaries that I do not want to re-download from the 3rd party site every time a PR is submitted to github. These binaries are used to test against, and the 3rd party publishes a release once every 6 months**

I have attempted to do this with the `upload-artifact` and `download-artifact` flow with github actions.

I first created an action to upload the artifacts. These are static binaries I would like to cache repository wide and re-use everytime a PR is opened.

Here is the commit that did that:

https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s/runs/2841148806

I pushed a subsequent commit and added logic to `download-artifact` on the same CI job. When it runs, it claims that there is no artifact with that name despite the prior commit on the same job uploading it

https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s/pull/3281/checks?check_run_id=2841381241#step:4:11

What am i doing wrong?

Next

Answer (score 1):

Artifacts and cache achieve the same thing, but should be used for different use cases. From the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows):

> Artifacts and caching are similar because they provide the ability to store files on GitHub, but each feature offers different use cases and cannot be used interchangeably.
>
> - Use caching when you want to reuse files that don't change often
>   between jobs or workflow runs.
> - Use artifacts when you want to save
>   files produced by a job to view after a workflow has ended.

In your case you could use caching and set up a `cache` action. You will need a `key` and a `path`, and it will look something like this:

```
    - name: Cache dmg
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        key: "bitcoin-s-dmg-${{steps.previoustag.outputs.tag}}-${{github.sha}}"
        path: ${{ env.pkg-name }}-${{steps.previoustag.outputs.tag}}.dmg
```

When there's a cache hit (your `key` is found), the action restores the cached files to your specified `path`.

When there's a cache miss (your `key` is not found), a new cache is created.

By using [contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions) you can update your `key` and observe changes in files or directories. E.g. to update the cache whenever your `package-lock.json` file changes you can use `${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}`.

Comment: My understanding of a cache is that it requires _redownloading_ artifacts on the first time a PR is opened. This is an improvement from our current flow which re-downloads them on every commit, but ideally we would just cache the artifact across the entire repo.

Comment: Cache stores dependencies **between** workflow runs on GitHub. So it is cached across the entire repo. This cache will be restored every time the workflow kicks off.